# summing up the values in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I created a dictionary with the following syntax

```
frequency_m= dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

which results into:

```
{0: 3512488, 1: 2606, 2: 3553, 3: 3929, ..........}
```

I want to classify the key, value pairs as binary - '1' or '0'. Below I represented

```
for k, v in frequency_m.iteritems():
    if k ==0:
        print '0', v
    else:
        print '1', sum(v)
```

obviously that generates `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`. I am sure I need to iterate over the values and sum that up for the values other than '0'. I am not getting it. Any thoughts?

```
0 3512488
1 2606
1 3553
1 3929
```

my goal here is to output the table as

```
0 3512488
1 10088
```

I tried following as well: `** np.sum((value for key, value in frequency_m.iteritems() if key != '0'))**`, it sums up all the values and does not yield my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your comprehension to check for `0` instead of `'0'`:

```
np.sum((value for key, value in frequency_m.iteritems() if key != 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, zipa. I am such a dumb.